# How to justify this general Taylor series argument given by physicists?

Tags: taylor-expansion, physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I'm a 3rd year Physics and Mathematics student, an in this 3 year, I always faced with arguments like this;

> Let $f(t)$ be a function of $t$. Then, for small $\delta >0$, we can
>   expand $f$ around $0$ by its Taylor series, so
>
> $f(\delta) = f(0) + \delta \frac{d f}{dt}|_{t = 0}  + O(\delta^2)$.
>
> Now, since $f$ satisfies this $\dots$ equality, by putting its taylor
>   expansion in that equality, we get  $$\text{(some terms involving
>  $\delta$)} + O(\delta^2) = 0.$$ Since, the terms in $O(\delta^2)$ are
>   much small compared to the other terms, in the limit $\delta \to 0$ we get
>
> $$\text{(some terms involving $\delta$)} = 0,$$ so this means the
>   coefficient of $\delta $ in LHS has to be zero, hence $\dots$.

I know that while doing physics, we do lots of assumption without explicitly stating them; however, since we are just building a model, as long as I can build a consistent machinery to duplicate the principles of the phenomena at hand, there is no problem.

**Question:**

However, assuming that the given above "mathematical" argument is still in the bounds of the known mathematics to mankind, how can one justify that, indeed, the coefficients of $\delta$ in the last line should be zero ?

To give a little more concrete example, say $f(0) = 0$ and the second term in the expansion is $\delta (K - K')$, so by the same argument,
$$\delta (K- K') + O(\delta^2) = 0 \Rightarrow K=K'.$$

But, in such a case, if $\delta \to 0$, then the term $\delta (K-K') \to 0$ or equal to zero, but a such a general argument ignores the fact that $\delta (K-K')$ might not be equal to zero, but is quite small, in which case $K = K'$ is not necessarily true.

**Edit:**

An example of such argument given in [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FTyQS3y2UU&feature=youtu.be&t=2466](https://youtu.be/3FTyQS3y2UU?t=2467).

Comment: Your YouTube link is to a treatment of $(1+ik\delta)^\dagger(1+ik\delta)=1+O(\delta^2)$ to linearise unitary operators. Note that if $k^\dagger=k$ the deviation from unitarity would be $O(\delta)$ instead.

Comment: @J.G. The provided argument is still the same, however. Plus, I didn't get it what should I supposed to understand from your second sentence.

Comment: The point is we get a $o(\delta)$ error, the smallest we can manage, by equating the coefficient $\delta$ coefficient to $0$, resulting in the derived condition. When you see an argument like this, the premise is that we solve equations to make the error as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see your point. The expression:
$$
\delta(K−K′)+O(\delta^2)=0
$$
means that the LHS is exactly $0$, not only in the limit $\delta\to0$ but for all values of $\delta$ in a certain neighbourhood of $0$ (at least). Dividing then both sides by $\delta$ and taking the limit $\delta\to0$ gives $K-K'=0$. That's perfectly rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

For a function differentiable in a neighbrohood of $0$, we can write rigorously

$$f(\delta)=f(0)+f'(0)\delta+o(\delta).$$

So if by other means you establish that

$$f(\delta)=f(0)+o(\delta^2),$$ then certainly $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: There is no any other means; the argument goes exactly as I outlined it.

Comment: If you like, I can directly send you a physics lecture video link where this is done.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: this makes no sense. The Taylor development alone does not allow allow you to conclude that the first derivative is zero. You must have missed something, like "at an extremum".

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: No, it is not an extremum; In fact, in the example I gave in the question (in the link), that coefficient will correspond to momentum operator in QM, which is definitely not the zero operator.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: the Taylor development alone does not imply that $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I know that; there are lots of counterexamples.

Comment: So obviously, either the argument in the lecture is wrong, or you missed something. By the way, do you really expect me to watch these 46 mins ?!

Comment: Well, ... that is pretty much all the sample space of possible events in this case, so ... I agree :)

Comment: The link should redirect you to 41:07, does it not doing that ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: the reason is explained before. Watch the video.

Comment: Actually, this is third time I'm watching that video, still don't get it.

Comment: @onurcanbektas: find what justifies $1+o(\delta^2)$.

Comment: I always assumed that the reason why there is $O(\delta^2)$ in that expression (RHS) is because we are ignoring that term in the LHS.Actually, if I didn't missed somehow, the professor does not give an argument why there should be $O(\delta^2)$ in the RHS.